# Reload second child popup window while closing the third popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, popup

I Have a default `aspx page` while clicking a button from that page like

GrandParent page >> Parent Page >> Child Page

these above three page are all window popup so when i click the parent page child page is popup open so what i need is when i close child page i need parent page to be refreshed or reload but instead of this it is refreshing the grandparent page and removing all the previous data.

**what i did is:**

```
function refreshAndClose() {
    window.opener.location.reload(true);
    window.close();
}
```

on client side and on code behind i have used the function

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "CloseAndRefreshParentWindow", "refreshAndClose();", true);
```

this above code reload only grandparent page not the parent page so guys need little help here.